# Actionscript 2.0 movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

So heres my situation.

I have a movieclip which has a button inside it.
A stop command on the first frame prevents the clip from playing by default and pressing the button results in it playing once. Now once the animation is finished I want to go another frame in a different scene.

Unfortunately the gotoandplay command doesn't seem to do anything.

To clarify the button is within a movieclip. I wanted to make a pop up menu.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, the `gotoAndStop()` function is used to move your `playhead` to frame 3 of Scene 2. This code needs to be placed on the main timeline:

```
myButton.onPress = function():Void {
    gotoAndStop("Scene 2", 3);
}
```

If your button myButton is in a movie clip myMovieClip, you need to target it:

```
myMovieClip.myButton.onPress = function():Void {
    gotoAndStop("Scene 2", 3);
}
```

**Remark**

> You can use the scene parameter only on the root timeline, not within
>   timelines for movie clips or other objects in the document.

Adobe help about: [jumping to a frame or scene](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000392.html).

Comment: Sorry if this is a noob question. Should I place the code on the main timeline or inside the movieclip.

Comment: @Mehul Sahai This code needs to be placed on the main timeline. If your button `myButton` is in a movie clip `myMovieClip`, you need to target it: `myMovieClip.myButton.onPress`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Right I put it on the main timeline but it doesn't seem do anything. Again to clarify yes I have the button inside the movie clip as a menu and on clicking the button it should go to scene 2

Comment: @Mehul Sahai If you try to write `trace("test");` in your function, and to test your movie, what happens?

Comment: "test" comes as output

Comment: @Mehul Sahai Are you sure that your scene's name is the same as the first argument of gotoAndStop?